# Netty not sending certain character sequences

Tags: java, netty

I started to familiarize myself with Netty since I plan to use it in a future project.

But I stumbled upon some weird behaviour.

Since I will be using a text protocol for the project, I started with the standard "text" pipeline with StringDecoder,StringEncoder and DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder. But now I have reduced this to the following:

```
EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
try {
    Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap(); 
    b.group(workerGroup); 
    b.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
    b.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ch.pipeline().addLast(new TestClientHandler());
        }
    });

    ChannelFuture f = b.connect("some.working.web.server", 80).sync();
    f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } finally {
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
}
```

And my TestClient is:

```
public static class TestClientHandler extends
            SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf> {

@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("channel active");
    ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(
      "GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\n", CharsetUtil.US_ASCII));
    System.out.println("after write");
}

@Override
public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg) {
    System.out.println("got" + msg);
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
    cause.printStackTrace();
    ctx.close();
}
}
```

I looked at the traffic with Wireshark and when this is executed only the TCP handshake is performed and nothing is sent. After a while the program exits (when the HTTP server closes the connection).

The weirdest thing is that if I change the line:

```
ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(
          "GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\n", CharsetUtil.US_ASCII));
```

to

```
ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(
          "GET /index.html HTTPA1.0\r\n", CharsetUtil.US_ASCII));
```

Then the "request" gets sent to the server which of course rejects it and replies with an error.

I played with the "request string" a bit more and it seems that Netty for some reason does not like the following:

```
ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(
                    " HTTP/1.0\n", CharsetUtil.US_ASCII));
```

This string does not get sent. But removing the leading whitespace, or changing a random character gets the string sent to the server.

And to make things even stranger, if I test this with a SMTP server, the "request" gets sent without problems to the server. The only difference is that the SMTP server sends the HELO message before my string is sent to the server...

The behaviour is also same with Netty 4.0.23 and 4.1.0.Beta3 on Java 1.7.0_21 and 1.8.0_20.
And also stays the same if I change to OioEventLoopGroup and OioSocketChannel

Also changing the channelActive method a bit:

```
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("channel active");
    ByteBuf bb = Unpooled.buffer();
    bb.writeBytes("GET index.htm HTTP/1.0\r\n".getBytes());
    System.out.println(ByteBufUtil.hexDump(bb));
    ctx.writeAndFlush(bb);
    System.out.println("after write");
}
```

Shows that my "request" got turned into proper sequence of bytes:

```
47455420696e6465782e68746d20485454502f312e300d0a
G E T   i n d e x . h t m   H T T P / 1 . 0 \r\n
```

I would appreciate if someone has an explanation for this wierdness...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem turned out to be caused by the antivirus software.
Apparently the software that I am using is using a hacky parser for HTTP monitoring and it ate my "request" which was in fact invalid... Missing extra \r\n at the end.

Turning antivirus off solved the problem. And also correcting the request to:

> GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n

Kept antivirus happy.

But why it decided to eat

> GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\n

and not

> GET /index.html HTTPA/1.0\r\n

is beyond me...